# Error with aws cli: EKS create cluster is not accepting accepted parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am trying to provision an EKS Cluster with AWS CLI. I followed the official documentation
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/eks/create-cluster.html

The issue is with the parameters. I tried to use the below command

```
aws eks create-cluster --name testControlPlane --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/EKS-Access --resources-vpc-config subnetIds=subnet-123,subnet=890,securityGroupIds=sg-456,endpointPublicAccess=false,endpointPrivateAccess=true
```

The error is

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in resourcesVpcConfig: "endpointPublicAccess", must be one of: subnetIds, securityGroupIds
Unknown parameter in resourcesVpcConfig: "endpointPrivateAccess", must be one of: subnetIds, securityGroupIds
```

Could someone help me with this

Comment: Are you using an old version of awscli?

Comment: Nope.. checked that using version2

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest 2.x. IIRC those features were added to EKS within the last 6mos